# Shouldn't we reverse the synonym relationship between the "currency" and "money" tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, reversed-synonyms

I'm sure I've brought this up before but I can't find the details now so here it is laid out:

We currently have a [currency](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) tag.

It has the synonym [money](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money).

But the concept of "currency" is more specific than the concept of money.

"Currency" generally means cash money or money of a specific country whereas "money" is a general term covering all forms of money.

Now generally a general term is a better "lead tag" or "head tag" of a group of synonyms than a specific term but let's examine this case. Maybe it's better to split the tag and use both?

As it turns out most questions tagged "currency/money" are general. There are a few about which of several possible currencies are more suitable in specific situations but not enough in my opinion to warrant a separate tag, and there are enough varied questions that the general term "money" maps better as a tag with our current questions than the specific term "currency".

What does the rest of the community think?

---

Well a surprising result for me! Now what should we do with the tag wiki which seems overly specific if it's to cover "money" as well as "currency"?

**tag wiki excerpt**

> Coins and banknotes issued from a government as a generally accepted medium of exchange.

**tag wiki**

> Coins and banknotes issued from a government or supranational organization as a generally accepted medium of exchange. Some examples are the US dollar (USD), euro (EUR) or Japanese Yen (JPY).
>
> Questions tagged [currency](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) relate to questions of obtaining, using and exchanging a particular currency in a particular country or region, and both electronic and cash transactions are covered.

Comment: Good on ya for the well-clarified options you've presented in your answers for voting.

Comment: I have given some thought to this, and decided to make 'currency' a synonym for 'money' ('money' is main tag) even though the community vote went for the opposite. Semantically, this is what makes sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**VOTE UP** to make "money" the main tag and "currency" its synonym.

**VOTE DOWN** to leave "currency" as the main tag and leave "money" as its synonym.

Comment: Wow really? Personally I can't understand how "currency" is better. Since it seems that multiple people and currently the majority hold this view, could somebody enlighten me? I must be missing something. Also check out the tag wiki text which was just submitted today and to me it takes the obvious approach of defining "currency" specifically rather than what the tag is used for generally.

Comment: I think these two tags aren't synonyms at all.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: For when you don't think they are synonyms [I have provided the other answer to be voted up/down](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/352/shouldnt-we-reverse-the-synonym-relationship-between-the-currency-and-money/354#354).

Answer (score 2):

**VOTE UP** to keep "currency" and "money" as synonyms, whichever ends up as the main tag.

**VOTE DOWN** to split "currency" and "money" into separate tags.